# toLocaleDateString not working properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, locale

I have two machines (on different development networks). On one machine if I manually set the language on Google Chrome to English UK, date format is correctly displayed as DD/MM/YYYY if I run the following within the Chrome developer tools console:

(new date()).toLocaleDateString()

On a separate network where I am managing the locale via GPO, the setting is correctly configured and the language is displayed in English UK, but if I run the above command the date is displayed as YYYY-MM-DD.

On each network my timezone is UTC+00:00. I cannot see any configurable difference - simply that one is manual and one is GPO.

The material online about this (including on StackOverflow) all seems to indicate that this should be working.

Comment: Sounds like the locale set via GPO is wrong. Open the developer tools in chrome (F12), go to console and enter `console.log(window.navigator.language);` then check if the output is en-GB

Comment: The result of [*toLocaleDateString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) is implementation dependent, you should not depend on it conforming to any particular preferences.

Comment: Hi Fels. I've tested the GPO implementation with Chrome v50 in the same environment and it correctly configures to en-GB with DD/MM/YYYY. I then install Chrome v58 on the same machine without making any other changes and it fails and gives me YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: In some cases when your locale is not supported a fallback language is used. If `Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf('en-GB')` returns an empty array then your locale is not supported in chrome.